# Java implementation power function With Recursion Efficiently

Tags: java, recursion

We should try long for this sort of methods

```
 long genericPow(int base,int exp){

    if(exp==0)return 1;
    if(exp==1)return base;
    if(exp==2)return base*base;
    if(exp==3)return base*base*base;

    return genericPow(base, 3)*genericPow(base, exp-3);


}
```

For instance, if you want to compute x^15, the method of exponentiation by squaring will give you:

```
x^14 = (x^3)*(x^11) 
x^11 = (x^3)*(x^8)
x^8 = (x^3)*(x^5)
x^5 = (x^3)*(x^2)
x^3 = x*x*x
```

thus it will turn down the loop complexity by 3.

Comment: What is the question here?

Comment: It doesn't reduce complexity - it will still take the same number of multiplications to calculate the result. It does reduce the stack size a little - but I doubt you gain much speed wise. I would suggest you benchmark with Caliper and post the result as an answer to your own question.

Comment: Also, what happens when exp = -1 ? :-)

Comment: Question was , Is there any better way.? @ Sinstein

Comment: I have not gone with the negative exp yet. @blagae

Comment: on top of what @blagae said, this algortihm doesn't cover the case of 0^0 which is undefined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 long pow(long x,int n){
    if(n<=0)return 1;
    if(n==1)return x;
    if(n==2)return (x * x);


    if(n%2==0){
        return pow(pow(x, n/2),2);
    }else{

        return x*pow(x, n-1);
    }




}
```

Complexity O(logn)

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite sure what is your question here. 
This doesn't reduce complexity as pointed out by Boris the Spider.
If you are trying to create an efficient algorithm to compute the power of x^n you can use a simple divide and conquer strategy. Note that x^n=(x^(n/2))^2 if n is even and x^n=x(x(n-1)/2)^2 if odd. Thus you can use this to build a recursive algorithm which can compute powers of a number efficiently.

Answer (score 0):

```
static int pow(int a, int b) {
    return powInner(a, b, 1);
}

static int powInner(int a, int b, int c) {
    return b > 0 ? powInner(a, b - 1, a * c) : c;
}
```

I guess this wasn't the point?